# Google Maps : Autocomplete - Giving results on typing 00000. How to avoid this?

Tags: google-maps

When i type 000  - Google Auto Complete gives suggestions for Addresses ? 
Why is that so ? What configuration I am missing here ? I cant attach images as I from Behind a Corporate Firewall but i will suggest the steps

1. Open maps.google.co.in
2. In Address type 000 - or till when address start appearing in Auto-Complete

The same behavior is in my Web using Maps plugin

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes addresses can contain 000. For example, I can see the following suggestion '000 East Rd, Herscher, IL, United States' or '00040 Metropolitan City of Rome, Italy'.

In India I can see the '000000, Surat, Gujarat, India' with place ID ChIJY24F8TJO4DsRxYHx189lhoY after execution of

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=000&components=country%3AIN&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Place details

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJY24F8TJO4DsRxYHx189lhoY&key=YOUR_API_KEY

shows the following position

[image]

As you can see this is establishment and it looks like the data is not correct. You can try to filter types by address to exclude establishments

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=000&types=address&components=country%3AIN&key=YOUR_API_KEY.

For data related issues, you can also use the "Report a problem" link on the bottom right corner of the maps.google.com.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

Hope it helps!